# Use font awesome inside an HTML 5 Web Component

Tags: html, font-awesome

I am getting started with HTML5 Web Components. I am using the `pollyfill webcomponents.js` and using chrome for development. How can I get font awesome to work inside a web component. I have tried both the cdn and the script tag they provide. I thought this would work:(but it didn't, also I omitted the js for brevity)

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
.month-title {
  height: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.day-body {
  height: 70%;
  padding: 10px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#title {
  height: 10%;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}
#monthTitle {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #4cff00;
}
.month-button {
  background-color: #ffd800;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/4483f1d3f2.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper snow">

  <div id="title">

    <div id="leftButton" class="month-button">

      <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>


    </div>

    <div id="monthTitle">

    </div>

    <div id="rightButton" class="month-button">

      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>


    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="month-title">

  </div>

  <div class="day-body">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The code looks just fine. Did you try downloading font awesome files and then use it? That will narrow the problem down.

Comment: The code snippet above seems to be working fine. The right and left arrows are showing here if you run it. Did you check it? Isn't that what you want?

Comment: This is inside a web component in the shadow dom. Its not just in a page.

Comment: @MichaelWRiemerJr did you found a solution by now?

Comment: heres a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546007/why-doesnt-font-awesome-work-in-my-shadow-dom)

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted this (replaced cdn) :

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
.month-title {
  height: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.day-body {
  height: 70%;
  padding: 10px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#title {
  height: 10%;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}
#monthTitle {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #4cff00;
}
.month-button {
  background-color: #ffd800;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="wrapper snow">

  <div id="title">

    <div id="leftButton" class="month-button">

      <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>

    </div>

    <div id="monthTitle">

    </div>

    <div id="rightButton" class="month-button">

      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>


    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="month-title">

  </div>

  <div class="day-body">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: if you go to font-awesome now they don't give you the link to the cdn. They email you the script tag. Also this is inside a web component. The client dom is encapsulated. That is the real problem I am having.