# Custom font not working in Stenciljs application

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, npm, stenciljs

I'm new to Stenciljs and I'm trying to get a custom font to work inside my app. I downloaded the otf file(Not sure if I need an npm package for this) Here's the code:

filestructure:

-src

--components

--assets

---Anurti-Regular.tiff

---Anurti-Regular.ttf

friends-listening.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Anurati-Regular';
  src: local('Anurati-Regular'),
   url('../assets/Anurati-Regular.tiff') format("tiff");
}

#home{
  background-color: #C8B7A6;
  height:1000px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Anurati-Regular;
}
```

friends-listening.tsx

```
<div id="home">
        <h2>Friends-FX app BETA</h2>
        <div id={this.login}>
          <my-component></my-component>
        </div>

        ...
</div>
```

Any help would be great. Thank you very much for your time,
Drew

I expected that the output would be that the font displays correctly on my front-end but no bueno.

Also, there have been a lot of questions around this idea, but no true answer

Comment: Format `tiff`? I think it should be `url('../assets/Anurati-Regular.ttf') format("truetype")` in your `@font-face` rule

Comment: I tried that as well. Neither worked. Thank you for youre response though. Also, I had a slight typo, the file type in the file structure is .tiff @herrstrietzel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where I was able to find a solution: [Why doesn't Font Awesome work in my Shadow DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546007/why-doesnt-font-awesome-work-in-my-shadow-dom)

1. Have a global.css file that includes this:

   ```
    @font-face {    
      font-family: 'Anurati-Regular';    
      src: local('Anurati-Regular'),    
      url('/assets/Anurati-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');    
    }
   ```
2. Have the .ttf file(Font file) downloaded. and inserted into your "assets" folder.
3. Have your assets file located in your "src" directory, but not inside your "components" directory

4. In your component .tsx file, for me (friends-listening.tsx) have "global.css" file referenced in the 'styleUrls' like the below:

   ```
    @Component({    
      tag: 'friends-listening',    
      styleUrls:[    
        'friends-listening.css',    
        '../../global.css'    
      ],    
      shadow: true,    
    })
   ```
5. Reference in your component's css file(for me friends-listening.css):

   ```
    #home{    
      background-color: #C8B7A6;    
      height:1000px;    
      text-align: center;    
      /*the below is the font-family solution*/
      font-family: 'Anurati-Regular';    
    }
   ```

Comment: `url('/assets/Anurati-Regular.ttf')` - like I said, your original relative path was invalid.

Comment: righto captain. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. Please thank by upvoting - it helps other readers know what might help them.

Comment: Thanks for the credits @Drew Y. I updated my original post from 2019 since there are two alternative solutions that weren't possible when I wrote it back in the day - sepcifically for StencilJS they might be worth checking out. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

How are you deploying Anurati-Regular.tiff? The path `../assets/Anurati-Regular.tiff` is relative to your CSS source code, but when running, your source code path is not relevant. That path needs to point to the location of the font file on your server, and your Stencil config needs to make sure that file is included when built.

There are multiple ways to deploy the font file or any other asset. You can include a copy task as part of your 'www' build - see https://stenciljs.com/docs/copy-tasks. Or you can include it by using the `assetsDir` feature in the `friends-listening` component - see https://stenciljs.com/docs/assets#making-assets-available. You could also deploy separately and point your CSS to an absolute url e.g. `url('https://my-server.com/assets/fonts/Anurati-Regular.ttf')`.

In any case, the `url()` value needs to point to the *served* location of the font file, not the source location.

Comment: So my "assets" folder in my "www" folder is in the same relative location as the "src" folder. It may have to do with Stencil not accepting the ttf file type or the otf file type. So I tried the tiff file type, but haven't found any documentation on that file type yet. Its just that the Tiff file type just the only font file type that StencilJS references in the documentation.

Comment: Not really - `../assets/Anurati-Regular.tiff` relative to `http://localhost:3333` is invalid I think - equates to `http://localhost:3333/../assets/Anurati-Regular.tiff`. Once again - how **and where** have you **deployed** the file?

Comment: Thank you for your help, @G. Tranter OI actually figured out the solution. I'll answer below.

Comment: Also, that had something to do with the Shadow DOM not being abel to translate that message effectively for some reason